# Sending the same System.Net.MaiL.MailMessage to multiple recipients

Tags: c#, email, mailmessage

I've got a method that basically has a "SendEmail" method (it will later be used by WCF service)

It has params like, Subject, Body, etc... and a string[] of Recipients.
What I do, is create a MailMessage based on the parameters, then send it using smtp - 
I know the MailMessage has a To MailAddressCollection, but if I add each address to that, the message is CC'd to each and every person in the collection.

What I want to do is send it to them seperateley.

Is there any way of doing this, other than creating a seperate mail message for each item in the Recipient array, and sending it that way?
I don't want to just BCC it to them either... as far as i know that's still recorded in the headers of the mail, and it's not particularly elegant.

Comment: BCC is not recorded in the mail header, the recipient(s) will never be able to see to whom else this mail was sent when you use BCC. The SMTP server filters out this message header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in this particular scenario you are restricted to creating a separate MailMessage object.

Comment: I agree, but you don't necessarily need to create a new object, just loop through the recipients array and change the TO address of the MailMessage object and then resend within the loop until you reach the last recipient.

Comment: how can i change the TO address..?
It's a collection - I can to a To.Clear() and then To.Add("my@address.com") or something similar...

Comment: @alex yes you would have to clear the list and add the new recipient

Comment: The only thing to keep in mind with this approach is that if you do have people CC'ed, they will get the email sent to them each time you send the email to a specific person.

Answer (score 1):

may be you can use something like this:

```
MailMessage msg= new MailMessage();
msg.Subject = *your subject text*;
msg.From = new MailAddress(*your address*, *your title*;);
msg.Body = *your body text*;;

foreach (DataRow row in dsRecipients .Tables[0].Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn col in dsRecipients .Tables[0].Columns)
    {
        msg.To.Clear();
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress((string)row[col]));
        server.Send(msg);
    }
}
```

where dsRecipients is a Dataset populated with your recipients.